# issue with richfaces tags

Tags: tags, richfaces

I'm working on a jsf1.2 project with richfaces3.3.2 framework.
i'm experiencing a strange problem with richfaces.org/rich namespace tags in Firefox, safari and chrome.
the problem is when i use rich validator or rich support tags the browser back button action to that page is clearing data from the components. ie does not have this issue. could any please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you check the managed bean scope in the faces config file. try changing to session scope.

```
 <managed-bean>
 <managed-bean-name>bean name</managed-bean-name>
 <managed-bean-class>bean packagename.classname</managed-bean-class>
 <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Austin... my managed bean is in session scope... that is the reason why it show the data in IE and a refresh after browser back in firefox...